# SQL server procedure return single dataset for multiple selects

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have written a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. It contains a CURSOR and within the Loop of the cursor some values are calculate and send to output using SELECT statement Like:

```
CURSOR START

SELECT OBJECT, REVENUE

CURSOR END
```

The problem is that when the execution completes its returns multiple tables for each row. I need to get a single table with all the rows. Is there a way to achieve this without using a TABLE?

**The main reason why I want it that way is when I execute procedure from PHP ODBC i just get the first row.**

Comment: Are you *certain* that you *must* use a cursor? Can you show us the code more completely? We may be able to show you alternatives.  Also, even if you do use a cursor, why *must* you avoid using a table?  Temp Tables and Table Variables seems perfectly appropriate here.

Comment: @dems Yes, now I am trying a table variable. Previously I did not know  about this feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE(field1 VARCHAR(50),field2 VARCHAR(50))
CURSOR START
    INSERT INTO @tmp
        ( field1, field2 )
    SELECT OBJECT, REVENUE

CURSOR END
SELECT * FROM @tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

`Insert` the **returned** values into a **temporary table / table variable** and then `select` from that after the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use some kind of table to store the temporary data. If you do not want to use a "real" database table, you can use a [temporary table](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42553/Quick-Overview-Temporary-Tables-in-SQL-Server-2005) or a [table variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx).

Those are constructs that, within the procedure, for all intents and purposes, behave like a table, yet are not actual tables in your database.

That said, using cursors to populate a table row-by-row is generally frowned upon in T-SQL, because, for one, cursors can be real performance bottlenecks. Try to see if you can somehow eliminate the use of the cursor completely, if could both speed up and simplify the code.